# i created nodered application in docker , i tried rebuild docker because i need using other cli tools. e,g:aws cli

Tags: node.js, docker, node-red

i need deploy to fargate, but nodered rebuild will follow hostname to create flow.json, this make me so hard to load old config to new nodered.
But now, if using docker run -h is work,but in fargate dose not work, how can i do?

Of course, release nodered docker version is solved this problem,but i don’t know how to call cli tools,if base on node-red, how can i install aws-cli2 and call it in nodered dashboard?

```
FROM nodered/node-red:latest
#USER root
RUN curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
CMD ["node-red"]
```

Comment: Why start from scratch and not just extend the official Node-RED images? Documentation for how to do this is in the official git repo and even includes a Dockerfile for a Debian based image if you don't want to use Apline. Also look at the node-red command line arguments, you can always pass in the flow file name

Comment: Yes,i know ,but How can I extend to use aws cli?

Comment: As you do with any other docker file, you use the `FROM` header to point to the official image then add the commands you want to use to extend.

Comment: ok, thanks your reply, i tried your method, it's very work for me, but install cli tools need root permission, i tried to use ```USER root``` but install after node-red user not work to call it,it will show ```/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: No such file or directory```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66797985/edit) the question to show all of the new `Dockerfile` and the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM nodered/node-red:latest
USER root
RUN curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
RUN rm -rf ./aws
USER node-red
```

But the problem is that the image is based on Alpine Linux which uses the musl standard libraries instead of glibc. And the AWS tools will not [work](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4971) with this runtime.

The easiest solution will be to use the Debian based build that I mentioned in the first comment. The docker file for that can be found [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-docker/tree/master/docker-custom), follow the instructions there to use the `docker-debian.sh` which will create an image called
`testing:node-red-build` which you can then use as the base for the Dockerfile I showed earlier:

```
FROM testing:node-red-build
USER root
RUN curl https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip -o awscliv2.zip
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
RUN rm -rf ./aws
USER node-red
```

Comment: it's great, i followed to do that, but dashboard show amazon config is NONE,what happent

Comment: That is a totally separate question to how to include the AWS CLI in the Node-RED container. Ask a new question with a detailed description of what you are trying to achieve.